# How to join two Document objects in elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch-dsl

I am attempting to create a "relationship" between two indexed Documents using elasticsearch-dsl. When using the `Object(EsPerson)` as a field of `EsComment`. When I update `EsPerson`, the field in `EsComment` does not update.

I have tried using InnerDoc, but that is not indexed and also does not update

```
class EsPersonAttr(InnerDoc):
    id = Long(required=True)
    name = Text(fields={'keyword': Keyword()}, required=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<EsPersonAttr: {}>'.format(
            self.name,
        )

class EsPersonIndex(Document):
    """
    Elastic Search Person model.
    """
    class Index:
        name = 'es-person'

    class meta:
        doc_type = 'es-person'

    id = Long(required=True)
    name = Text(fields={'keyword': Keyword()}, required=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        return super(EsPersonIndex, self).save(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<EsPersonIndex: {}>'.format(
            self.name,
        )


class EsPerson(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self._id = id
        self._name = name

        self.index_doc = EsPersonIndex(
            id=id,
            name=name
        )

        self.attr_doc = EsPersonAttr(
            id=id,
            name=name
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<EsPerson: {}>'.format(
            self._name,
        )

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    # Set both Document & InnerDoc at the same time
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value

        # self.index_doc.id = value
        self.index_doc.update()

        self.attr_doc.id = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._id

    @name.setter
    # Set both Document & InnerDoc at the same time
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

        self.index_doc.name = value
        self.index_doc.save()

        self.attr_doc.name = value


class EsComment(Document):
    """
    Elastic Search Comment model.
    """
    id = Long(required=True)
    title = Text(fields={'keyword': Keyword()}, required=True)
    text = Text(fields={'keyword': Keyword()})
    author = Object(EsPersonAttr, required=True)

    class Index:
        name = 'es-comment'

    class meta:
        doc_type = 'es-comment'

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        # if there is no date, use now
        return super(EsComment, self).save(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<EsComment: {}>'.format(
            self.title,
        )
```

I expected that when I updated the name field for a EsPerson, it updates author.name in EsComment

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the example using `parent`/`child` and `nested` which ar the two methods of joining objects in Elasticsearch: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/examples/parent_child.py

Comment: Are the strings in the dict's in `Join(relations={'question': 'answer'})` relating to the index name. So in my example it would be `Join(relations={'es-comment': 'es-person'})`. Do they need to be sub-classes of the same parent object, `Post` in the example?

Comment: not to index name, just the "types" of documents that serve as parent and children. They don't have to be sub-classes but since they ultimately need to be in the same index and probably thus share a bunch of fields that is an easier and more straightforward approach